# Loss function trainable parameters are not working in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, loss-function

```
en = encoder(encoder_input)
de = decoder(en[0])
vae = keras.Model(encoder_input, [en, de])

reconstruction_loss1 = tf.keras.metrics.mse(encoder_input, de[0]) * n_inputs

reconstruction_loss2 = tf.keras.metrics.mse(en[1], de[1]) * (2*n_inputs)
reconstruction_loss3 = tf.keras.metrics.mse(en[2], de[2]) * n_inputs


l1_weight = tf.Variable(0.5, trainable=True, name='L1_Loss_weight')
l2_weight = tf.Variable(0.5, trainable=True, name='L2_Loss_weight')
l3_weight = tf.Variable(0.5, trainable=True, name='L3_Loss_weight')

loss = l1_weight*reconstruction_loss1 + l2_weight*reconstruction_loss2 + l3_weight*reconstruction_loss3

vae.add_loss(loss)
```

for the multiple outputs of the encoder and decoder, I calculated the loss and it is working. But when i added the trainable variable, I saw the training parameters of add_loss is zero which means these variables are not updating . I want to train all the variables of l1_weight, l2_weight, l3_weight so that it can automatically control the loss function.  What is the good way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting those `tf.Variable` as attributes of the model.

```
vae.l1_weight = tf.Variable(0.5, trainable=True, name='L1_Loss_weight')
vae.l2_weight = tf.Variable(0.5, trainable=True, name='L2_Loss_weight')
vae.l3_weight = tf.Variable(0.5, trainable=True, name='L3_Loss_weight')

loss = vae.l1_weight*reconstruction_loss1 + vae.l2_weight*reconstruction_loss2 + vae.l3_weight*reconstruction_loss3
vae.add_loss(loss)
```